# Decompressing Image into the memory and loading it in picturebox

Tags: c#

Hey guys How can I decompress compressed image file into the memory and load it in picturebox? I tried this with a text file and it worked, I was able to read its content.

```
public string Decompress (string file)
{
      GZipStream gzIn = new GZipStream(File.OpenRead(file), CompressionMode.Decompress);
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(gzIn);
      string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
      sr.Close();
      return content;
}
```

Comment: Image myBitmap = new Bitmap(stream);

Comment: You should never ever use string encoding for binary data. It's not round-trippable for arbitrary binary data because it's not intended to be. What I mean by that is that if you convert byte[] -> string -> byte[] (and files are ultimately read as bytes), then the byte[] you start with likely won't match the byte[] you end up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Image.FromStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) method.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot about that :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use below code use Image.FromStream to load image

```
GZipStream gzIn = new GZipStream(File.OpenRead(file), CompressionMode.Decompress);
var image = Image.FromStream(gzIn);
 pictureBox.Image = image;
```